# How to start process from within PowerShell in Admin mode?

Tags: powershell, administrator

After starting PowerShell in Administrator mode, I start Visual Studio with `start MyProject.sln`. Unfortunately, this does not start Visual Studio in Administrator mode. How can I modify the `start` command to do so?

Comment: It might help to edit the compatibility settings for devenv.exe - See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1074835/make-visual-studio-solution-filessln-always-executed-as-administrator) for full description...

Answer (score 2):

For people still coming to this a year later, you need to start the devenv process and pass your solution file in as part of the argument list, then use the `runAs` verb. For example:

```
start-process devenv.exe -ArgumentList "C:\path\to\solution.sln" -Verb runAs
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? This will launch a program with Administrator privileges.

```
start-process MyProject.sln -Verb runas
```

I tested it out like the following and it launched VS with Administrative privileges.

```
start-process devenv.exe -Verb runas
```

Comment: 'start-process : This command cannot be run due to the error: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation.' Strangely, without the '-Verb runas' it works fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: Check your file associations in windows maybe? Make sure .sln files are associated to launch with your version VS. In windows 10 it is "Choose a default app for each type of file"

Comment: Yes; It is associated. 'start myproj.sln' launches VS just fine. Is there a particular association I should be looking for? Should I be putting 'admin' on the end?

Comment: Did you try using devenv.exe instead of your .sln file? I don't ever need to put 'admin' on the end of that command.

Comment: Hopefully someone with more knowledge than myself comes along to view your question and add some input.